# use custom route with RedirectToAction (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use the RedirectToAction with parameters in my action method

```
return RedirectToAction("ListThreads", "View", new { category = "1", subcategory = "49"});
```

After redirect the url comes out like this
http://domain/Forum/View/ListThreads?category=1&subcategory=49

I want it to be generated like
http://domain/Forum/View/ListThreads/1/49

How to do it?

Note : I already have a route in global.asax that is used by all the pages/links.

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Forum_subcategory",
            "Forum/{controller}/{action}/{category}/{subcategory}",
            new { controller = "View", action = "ListThreads", category = "", subcategory = "" }
        );
```

Answer (score 14):

I had a simular problem with routing in my application, to fix my problem I used: **RedirectToRoute**.  If you change your RedirectToAction to this:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Forum_subcategory", new { controller = "View", action = "ListThreads", category = "1", subcategory = "49" });
```

You should get the result you are looking for.  For more information the Controller.RedirectToRoute Method refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Not Working for me :(

Answer (score 2):

I've seen similar issues before. As crap as it sounds, you might have to wrap your object in a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
return RedirectToAction("ListThreads", "View", new RouteValueDictionary(new { category = "1", subcategory = "49"}));
```

Give it a try, see how it goes.